# Css file caching

Tags: css, caching

I have a system where cache max-age is set to 0 and there is problem, when I have made some changes in my style.css fail the changes dont apear to client. Browser will use the old cached version of css.
I have simple question: Does naming css file as style.css?123 will be cached as a new?

Comment: are you using IIS server or Apache?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, adding a unique query string to the resource's URI will force the client to fetch a "fresh" version (since the client doesn't know that it's merely an *update* of a previously cached resource). This is known as **fingerprinting** and you typically use a timestamp or an incrementing version number<sup>1</sup> of the CSS file.

Google Web Fundamentals has a great article on [HTTP cache optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#invalidating_and_updating_cached_responses). Especially the section titled *"Invalidating and updating cached responses:"*

> **How do you get the best of both worlds: client-side caching and quick updates?** You change the URL of the resource and force the user to download the new response whenever its content changes. Typically, you do this by embedding a fingerprint of the file, or a version number, in its filename—for example, style.**x234dff**.css.

Do note, that the fingerprint does not need to be a sequential number. Any value – hash, version, etc. – will do as long as the risk of collisions is limited.

---

<sup>1)</sup> This is what's done here on SO, e.g. `http://sstatic.net/js/global-login.js?v=12`

Comment: Apparently, using the query string parameters is bad. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13377291/637609

Answer (score 2):

You can append a unique query string, although this will use bandwidth.

You can rename your CSS file every time you make a change, IE:

main-v1.css
main-v2.css
main-v3.css

And then re-reference it in your pages.  This saves bandwidth and forces browsers to reload it.

Comment: How will `main.css?v1` use more bandwidth than `main-v1.css`? (I guess I've misread your answer.)

Comment: main.css?v1 is actually the same, I meant for datestamping, it would load it every single time, when you only need it to load when there has been a change.  Naming the css file differently on each change, or adding a querystring of version number are the 2 best ways.

Comment: Apparently, using the query string parameters is bad. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13377291/637609

Answer (score 1):

yes, appending a querystring parameter in each `style.css` file will force it to cache again.
because browser caches each static component with its url, so when url is changed, the new file will be cached.

Comment: Apparently, using the query string parameters is bad. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13377291/637609

Answer (score 1):

You can trick the browser into thinking it's a new stylesheet every second by timestamping your CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
```

Which will give you this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?Thursday 24th of April 2008 04:45:21 PM" />
```

Taken from: [Can We Prevent CSS Caching?](http://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/)

Comment: Apparently, using the query string parameters is bad. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13377291/637609

Answer (score 1):

Using .htaccess file, you can define caching control on you files with special extensions.

You could include the following code in a .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

For more information about .htaccess file, see [Apache .htaccess Guide](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)