# What is the name for the strategy of naming static web content with a hash of the content to enable long caching times?

Tags: browser-cache

E.g. naming your JavaScript as `foo-e65325060020bef3804f867dd6bae598.js`, where `e65325060020bef3804f867dd6bae598` is a hash of the content of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fingerprinting:

- [Css file caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095487/css-file-caching)
- [What is Fingerprinting and Why Should I Care?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care)

It allows you to send a link to a different file-name when a peripheral asset file (javascript, css or image files) changes on the main webpage. The change in file-name causes the browser to re-download any assets which have been changed.