# How to ensure broswer does not cache my JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, browser-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Css file caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095487/css-file-caching)

I want to ensure users always get the latest version of my code.

However setting it up so that browsers do not cache the files is bad as it would need to be loaded fresh every page view. I want to ensure it doesn't use a cached copy from a previous release. Eg. using a cached copy of the release 1.2 JS with version 1.3 site.

One way I have seen involves changing the filename on each release and linking to that different file name on each release (eg 'myscript1.3.js') This seems a lot of effort and slightly hacky.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: check this its aint  good practice http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: @NullPointer not a duplicate of the first 2 - maybe of the third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a perfectly good solution, and I would even go so far as to say that it's the best.

You could also use query parameters to indicate a new version (?v=1, ?v=2, ...). But this could throw off some public proxies (they might not cache the files). See here for details: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageProxyCaching

Off course this will require some effort on your part. But you can automate all of this in your deploy process (how to do that would depend entirely on your setup, so I can't give you a solution without knowing a lot more about your project).

Comment: would someone care to elaborate as to why this is downvoted? - or was it just revenge by @Rab Nawaz?

Comment: @Jan Han... If I could, I would have just Up-voted...

Answer (score -1):

Method 1 : You alter server headers.These might be different for different servers but for apache servers you can have a look at the mod_cache module http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html

Method 2 : You use some meta tags.You'll find a related question here [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

Comment: This would force refresh each page view, not each release of the site. Which is bad for performance