# Browser Cache on production site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, caching, w3-total-cache

I have a site which is in production.

WordPress 3.7.1 + W3 Total Cache (I know it's not conected with browser cache)

I updated some files (css, some php and js)

with W3 Total Cache, I combine and minify css (which automatically generates name)
So I cleaned minify cache + changed javascript version

`wp_register_script( 'scrips', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.3', true );`

I asked some users and they gave me their screenshots and they have a problem with browser cache (probbly css). As soon as they clean their cache, problems are gone.

What should I do? Users are coming back )

Comment: There are a variety of techniques in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Comment: Interesting read. I think `auto-versioning` is a bit overkill for websites that only ever have one version (latest).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend fingerprinting. I find it the best strategy for caching files like minified CSS and JavaScript.

[Css file caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095487/css-file-caching)

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

Whether you use E-Tags, a custom URL or a GET-parameter is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use the *W3 Total Cache plugin* on your *WordPress* website until it's design & development is finalized! Serving cached production files on an unfinished website defeats the purpose of the benefits of the caching plugin!

Finish your website, activate the caching mechanism plugin and avoid problems like the one you are experiencing.

**Update:** Possible duplicate of question **[What is an elegant way to force browsers to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)**

Comment: You seem to be femiliar with this plugin, could you please update your answer how to get rid of this problem, for example, if I disable browser cache for css (expire, eTag, control header), would this solve my problem