# Windows Phone 8, changes to javascript not getting applied when deployed

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

When I'm making changes to javascript files and reload my app to a device or the emulator my changes are not there, is there some sort of caching going on? I've tried cleaning the solution  to no avail. even removing the script reference from the html file but it's still there when loaded.
What's extra weird is the output window seems to detect a change and loads everything again but none of my changes are applied

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using fingerprinting.

[Css file caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095487/css-file-caching)

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

Whether you use E-Tags, a custom URL or a GET-parameter is up to you.